Multiplicative formula of the binomial coefficient Proof
Let $1\leq k \leq n$, Proof that $$\binom{n}{k} = \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n+1-i}{i}$$
By induction, it holds for $k=1$, and assume it's true for $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
              \binom{n+1}{k+1}
              &= \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!\big((n+1)-(k+1)\big)!}\\
              &= \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!\big(n+1-k-1\big)!}\\
              &= \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}\\
              &= \frac{n!(n+1)}{k!(k+1)(n-k)!}\\
              &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{n+1}{k+1}\\
              &= \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n+1-i}{i} \cdot \frac{n+1}{k+1}\\
              &= \frac{n+1}{k+1}\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n+1-i}{i}\\
              &= \frac{n+1-k}{k+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{(n+1)+1-i}{i}\\
              &= \frac{(n+1)+1-(k+1)}{k+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{(n+1)+1-i}{i}\\
              &= \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{(n+1)+1-i}{i}
            \end{align*}
I'm having trouble showing why $\frac{n+1}{k+1}\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n+1-i}{i}
              = \frac{n+1-k}{k+1} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{(n+1)+1-i}{i}$ holds true. Can you help me finish my proof? By showing why that equation is true. Thanks

Note that
\begin{align}&\binom nk\\
=&\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
=&\frac{n!/(n-k)!}{k!}\\
=&\frac{n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\cdots\times(n-k+1)}{1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times k}\\
=&\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n+1-i}{i}
\end{align}

You can't apply induction on both two variables.
For this question, the number $n$ is fixed but $k$ varies, so you should induct on the variable $k$ only. That is, the inductive step is to prove the identity for $\binom{n}{k+1}$ rather than for $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.
The proof for $\binom{n}{k+1}$ is not hard for you from your presentation here: $$\binom{n}{k+1}=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}.$$
Simply apply the induction hypothesis to the last equation here.

This is arguably just a definition of the binomial coefficient, no induction needed provided you can accept that
$$
m! = \prod_{i=1}^m i
$$
and that by definition
$$
\binom n k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
Clearly,
$$\newcommand{\=}[1]{\stackrel{(#1)}{=}}
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{n+1-i}{i}
&\=1  \frac{\prod_{i=1}^k n+1-i}{\prod_{i=1}^k i} \\
&\=2  \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{i=1}^k n+1-i \\
&\=3  \frac{1}{k!} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n n+1-i}{\prod_{i=k+1}^n n+1-i} \\
&\=4  \frac{n!}{k!} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n  i}{\prod_{i=k+1}^n n+1-i} \\
&\=5  \frac{n!}{k!} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=k+1}^n n+1-i} \\
&\=6  \frac{n!}{k!} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n-k} i} \\
&\=7  \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} \\
&\=8 \binom n k
\end{align*}$$
Explanations:

$(1)$ is just splitting the product across numerator and denominator.
$(2)$ applies the definition of the factorial.
$(3)$ appends factors indexed by $i=k+1,k+2,\cdots,n$ to the top and bottom of the fraction, which would cancel normally.
$(4)$ follows by reindexing the product (say, by $j := n+1-i$). Notice that, if you explicitly write the product out, it goes backwards in comparison to the "usual" factorial definition.
$(5)$ is the definition of factorial.
$(6)$ is another reindexing.
$(7)$ is the definition of factorial.
$(8)$ is the definition of the binomial coefficient.


What's the general property you're using in (3)?

Basically just that
$$
\frac xw = \frac{x \cdot y \cdot \ldots \cdot z}{w \cdot y \cdot \ldots \cdot z}
$$
Notice that the factors added on top and bottom are the same ones, so they would cancel out. It's less a property than it is an algebraic trick: I give the product factors as indexed by $i=k+1,k+2,k+3,$ etc., but to maintain its value I have to divide by each of those too.
